# Laplace transform of multiplication of two terms with different arguments

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace Transform of the product of two functions with different arguments?
The function is: $\mathcal{L}( \sin({3 t}) \cos({5 t}) )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use  [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) , $$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$

and we [know](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html), $$L\{\sin(at)\}=\dfrac a{s^2+a^2}$$